# Passing model parameters into a mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose model that has an association with a user model e.g.

```
var exampleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   <some more fields>
   userId: { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});

var Example = mongoose.model('Example', userSchema)
```

When I instantiate a new model I do:

```
// the user json object is populated by some middleware 
var model = new Example({ name: 'example', .... , userId: req.user._id });
```

The model's constructor takes a lot of parameters which has become tedious to write and refactor when the schema changes. Is there way of doing something like:

```
var model = new Example(req.body, { userId: req.user._id });
```

Or is the best way to create a helper method to generate a JSON object or even attach the userId to the request body? Or is there way that I haven't even thought of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
_ = require("underscore")

var model = new Example(_.extend({ userId: req.user._id }, req.body))
```

or if you want to copy userId into req.body:

```
var model = new Example(_.extend(req.body, { userId: req.user._id }))
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly, you'll be good trying the following:

```
// We "copy" the request body to not modify the original one
var example = Object.create( req.body );

// Now we add to this the user id
example.userId = req.user._id;

// And finally...
var model = new Example( example );
```

Also, **do not forget to add in your Schema options** `{ strict: true }`, otherwise you may be saving unwanted/attackers data.

Comment: strict is enabled by default since mongoose 3.

Comment: `Object.create` doesn't seem like the right fit here as that doesn't copy `req.body`, it uses it as a prototype object.  Pretty sure Mongoose will ignore the prototype's properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since Node 8.3, you can also use [Object Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
var model = new Example({ ...req.body, userId: req.user._id });
```

Note that order matters, with later values overriding previous ones.