# Mongoose save all parameters from request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm setting up a little API, I do some data validation on the client side of my application and whilst I do that I'm structuring my data to match my mongoose schema.

I'm attempting to do this...

```
router.route('/car')
.post(function(req, res) {
    var car = new Car();

    car = req.body; // line under scrutiny

    car.save(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.status(200);
            res.json({
                message: req.body.name + ' successfully registered!'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

but of course, this is currently removing all the model parameters of `car` provided by mongoose, so the save method e.t.c are no longer functional.

I have attempted `car.data = req.body` but this requires all of my mongoose schemas to be wrapped into a `data` object which isn't so elegant.

I was wondering if there was any way to avoid preparing the `car` object to be saved without the long-hand of;

```
car.name = req.body.name;
car.seats = req.body.seats;
car.engine_size = req.body.engine_size;
```

e.t.c.

I'm essentially wanting to do the equivalent of `car.push(req.body);` but again, the `.push()` method is not available to mongoose models.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass the `req.body` to your `Car` like this

```
var car = new Car(req.body);
```

Here's also a reference:
[Passing model parameters into a mongoose model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959199/passing-model-parameters-into-a-mongoose-model)

Comment: My question is: is this secure? Like... couldn't someone include a function `save` inside `req.body` and mess with the entire thing?